# Can JOSSO works without cookies? And how is the session checking process?

Tags: session, cookies, cookieless, josso

My team is now doing a project with the needs of single sign-on. So JOSSO is the solution chosen for our problem. We are using JOSSO 1.8.6.

For security purpose, we won't use cookies at all. But in JOSSO, it seems that after user authenticated, JOSSO will create cookie.

My question is, is it possible to config JOSSO to don't use cookie and still work perfectly?
If it impossible, i want to know why. Also how is the JOSSO session process that makes it needs to make cookie?

I have been looking for this problem, but can't find the solution. Any feedback will be much appreciated. Thanks.